# how to stop $webapp.Parent.ApplyWebConfigModifications() updating all web applications in farm

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepointadmin

$webapp.Parent.ApplyWebConfigModifications() updates all the webapplications in the farm.

For e.g. i have 2 web applications in my sharepoint farm.

webapp1
webapp2

I have web.config updates in webapp1 and below is the code using powershell

```
$webapp = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication]::Lookup($url)
$change = new-object "Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification"
$webapp.WebConfigModifications.Add($change)
$webapp.Update()
$webapp.Parent.ApplyWebConfigModifications()
```

this code works for webapp1 and webapp2 **but** when i run it for webapp2 i see an update in webapp1 config file also. Am i missing anything here ????

Comment: Is this issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

When you use SPWebConfigModication, the change is saved in the SharePoint configuration databases and populated out to all web.config files in the farm. Please see the following articles:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb861909(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb861909%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebservice.applywebconfigmodifications(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebservice.applywebconfigmodifications%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: I am using the same logic from powershell to update the web.config file in WebApplications. But when i rerun the same update in webapp2 i see that the config entry is added again in webapp1.  So the question here is how do i stop the updates happening in webapp1 when i am interested to update on webapp2. Note: I have run the above script twice once for each web application